# Does Qt platform for Linux support X5800?

Tags: java, qt, symbian

4 months ago, after many installations of sdk, qt, libraries, mameo etc. I realized that Qt simulator for touch devices only supports windows. We linux users could only use button based old phone sim.

I'm in the forum.nokia site searching for and improvement for 20 mins. Couldnt find any related information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X5800 is symbian based phone, You can download Qt for symbian SDK from here,

http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/symbian/

Here are some tutorial videos for your help,

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/12/03/tutorial-videos-qt-development-for-symbian/

Here is a good book for Qt for Symbian.

[http://www.amazon.com/Qt-Symbian-Frank-H-Fitzek/dp/0470750103](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470750103)

Happy Hacking!